# Append item to a specified list in a list of lists (Python)

Tags: python, list, append

I'm practicing my progamming skills by solving problems from project euler at the moment, and now I've come across some (in my opinion) strange behavior on Python.

When I do:

```
list = [[1]]*20
```

I get a list of 20 lists containing element 1, as expected. However, when I would like to append a 2 to the third element from this list, I would do that as follows:

```
list[3].append(2)
```

This however changes ALL the elements in the list. Even when I take a detour, like:

```
l = list[3]
l.append(2)
list[3] = l
```

All my elements get changed. Can anyone please tell me how to do this and get an output like so:

```
[[1], [1], [1], [1, 2], [1] .... [1]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Python lists are mutable objects, so when you do `[[1]]*20` it creates **one** list object `[1]` and then places 20 references to it in the toplevel list.

As far as the mutability problem is concerned, this is the same as the following

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
b.append(4)
a # [1,2,3,4]
```

This happens because `b=a` merely copies the *reference* to the list instance from `a` to `b`. They are both referring to the same actual list.

In order to create a list of lists, like you tried above, you need to create a unique list for each entry. A list comprehension works nicely:

```
mainlist = [[1] for x in range(20)]
mainlist[0].append(2)
mainlist # [[1,2],[1],[1],...]
```

**Edit**

As an aside, since type names are metaclasses in Python, naming your variables by the type name is a bad idea.
The reason is that can cause several issues further down in the code:

```
a = range(3) # [0,1,2]
type(a) # (type 'list')
isinstance(a, list) # True
```

Now, create a variable named `list`

```
list = range(3)
list # [0,1,2]
isinstance(list, list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

Not to mention, now you cant use the `list()` operator

```
c = list((1,2,3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I just didn't get where the bug in my program was until I found out about this curiosity. Good to know this, thank you. :)

Comment: Actually I noticed the problems mentioned in your edit earlier. This was just for the purpose of the example, won't do it again.

Comment: @SanderKersten No worries. I just figured it was worth addressing since it seems to come up every so often... I used to make that mistake in my own code every time I would play around with a small three-line function in my editor, and then copy it over into a bigger program and break everything, so I had to get myself in the habit of just never using type names for variables.

Comment: My most typical downfall would be `for list in lists` or any `for <type> in <type>s` sort of iterator, that would keep the variable name for the entire scope in which the loop ran.