# How to insert a value into a list of lists

Tags: python, list

`[[1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  **2**,     # <-- HERE
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3]]`

Here is my current output.  If you look at the line above, there is a `2` by itself.
This is the code I used

```
                    someList.insert((index), 2)
```

Is there any way to have that `2` be inside the previous index for ex

`[[1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 2], # <-- HERE
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append item to a specified list in a list of lists (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511867/append-item-to-a-specified-list-in-a-list-of-lists-python)

Answer (score 5):

Erm...

```
someList[index].append(2)
```